# How to make byobu forward-word and backward-word with CTRL+arrow?

Tags: shell, zsh, ergonomics, byobu

When used in uxterm zsh is jumping words when I press `ctrl+left` and `ctrl+right`.
When used in plain unconfigured byobu (tmux backend) it is not. The cursor sits there doing nothing.

I can however achieve that by using alt+b and alt+f, but I'd really like to use ctrl+arrow in keeping with general system-wide ergonomics.

Comment: I tried running both screen and tmux separately and they both block the ctrl+arrow motions. So it seems the problem affects both backends of byobu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found a workaround :

```
bindkey '^[[1;5D' backward-word
bindkey '^[[1;5C' forward-word
```

in `~/.zshrc`

To find out the arcane key code I had to `cat -v` and enter them. Gosh my productivity went up 15%.

Answer (score 7):

Create `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` with this value:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

Then add the following to `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux`

```
unbind-key -n C-Left
unbind-key -n C-Right
```

Comment: I would really have liked it to work (Ubuntu 12.04 / Unity / Standard Byobu with Tmux backend) But thank you anyway.

Comment: @xaccrocheur, interesting. I tested this out on Ubuntu 12.10 /Unity/ Byobu before posting and it worked for me..puzzling.

Comment: @xaccrocheur, dumb question perhaps but did you restart byobu after applying config changes?

Comment: Each time I exit all byobu windows by C-d back to gnome-terminal, and re-launch byobu. I tested some ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf edits, and it does indeed re-sources it.

Comment: My problem was with M-Left and M-Right instead of C.

Answer (score 2):

The patch here correct the problem for me on Ubuntu 12.04

https://code.launchpad.net/~jake-biesinger/byobu/byobu/+merge/126830